# Making a unique attribute in an already existing table NOT unique - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

A non-unique attribute of a table can be made unique by the query:

```
ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD UNIQUE (columnName);
```

I need to set a already unique attribute of a table NON-unique. Can anyone help me with the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alter table mytbl drop index columnName;
```

Use the above command for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Drop it, like so:

```
 ALTER TABLE yourTable DROP INDEX ItsName;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b54373/1)

Answer (score 1):

you can drop the unique index with the following statement:

ALTER TABLE `mytbl` DROP INDEX `columnName`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to get name of index, you can do that by [`SHOW INDEX IN mytbl`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html), then you can just [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE mytbl DROP INDEX auto_index_name;
```